# Execute JS config (Object) before parsing to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, config

How to execute functions inside JavaScript file (config for my backend server) before parsing to JSON?

**Example:**
`config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    structure_layout: {
        BUILDING: "BUILDING",
        FLOOR: "FLOOR",
        ROOM: "ROOM",
    },
    structure: {
        HOUSE: {
            type: function () {
                return this.structure_layout.BUILDING
            }
        },
        FLAT: {
            type: function () {
                return this.structure_layout.FLOOR
            }
        },
    }
};
```

Expected `config.json` after parsing:

```
{
  "structure_layout": {
    "BUILDING": "BUILDING",
    "FLOOR": "FLOOR",
    "ROOM": "ROOM"
  },
  "structure": {
    "HOUSE": {
      "type": "BUILDING"
    },
    "FLAT": {
      "type": "FLOOR"
    }
  }
}
```

Right now with `JSON.stringify` I am getting empty `type` attributes

Is it possible?

Is there any other way to define `js` version of config without usage of functions with same result?

Comment: This isn't JSON, this is just a JavaScript object literal. JSON is text, not code.

Comment: How does this get from `config.js` to `config.json`?

Comment: @Barmar as I described: By `JSON.parse()`

Comment: You don't call `JSON.parse()` when you have an object, you use that when you have a string and need to turn it into an object. `import` will get the object.

Comment: You're doing it backwards. You use `JSON.parse()` when you're reading `config.json`. You use `JSON.stringify()` to create `config.json` after using `import obj from config.js`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, yes, youre right, I have mistake in quersion. Sure I am using JSON.stringify...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run code before assigning `module.exports`. You don't need functions, just assign what you want to the properties.

```
const config = {
    structure_layout: {
        BUILDING: "BUILDING",
        FLOOR: "FLOOR",
        ROOM: "ROOM",
    },
    structure: {}
};

config.structure.HOUSE = {type: config.structure_layout.BUILDING};
config.structure.FLAT = {type: config.structure_layout.FLOOR};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Config in this example is very simplified... My actual config is like 1000 rows so having 1000 times `config.structure.` in there seems pretty bad idea...

Comment: Is there a general pattern? If so, you could write a function that maps from `structure_layout` to `structure`.

Comment: But the general point is that you can do whatever you want to compute the structure dynamically, then assign to `module.exports` at the end.